# Hazelcast Initializing cluster partition table

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am worried because i get this trace log after starting a Hazelcast Instance:

```
com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
[10.XXX.XXX.XXX]:5701 [dev] [3.7] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
```

*Tested with last version of Hazelcast 3.7 but the same with 3.6, and using  default Hazelcast config in a multicast environment*

I dont get any more trace related with this and looks that still is "*Initializing Cluster Partition"*, but everything works fine !

Everything works fine apparently,  get from imaps, put objects, synchronize with remote members of a cluster....

What does it mean exactly? It is a sign that something is wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is a necessary operation. The partition table assignment is created on first use of partitions (like put / get / ... operations) and gets generated on the fly. So this is a perfectly fine log :)

Comment: Yes, but i was worried because the log gets there, with no more information . There is no log  " Cluster partition table arrangement finished", or similar  :)  Just only when another instance of Hazelcast is joined shows more logs : com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptorThread,   Accepting socket connection  ....Thank you!

Comment: Actually it hangs on my computer (Arquillian tests + Payara); it seems it is blocked by something with no timeout, one CPU core is on 100% load and disconnecting the network did not help.
It started without any change of code so I still have no clue why ... Hazelcast version is 3.9.3.

Comment: Forget it ... it was my fault, I had a never ending loop in mock producer injected by tests :D